# Error Validator.php line 3162 in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

> BadMethodCallException in Validator.php line 3162: Method [validateThisFieldIsRequired] does not exist.

When I dont't provide data to the field than it is inserted successfully, but I provide data to the field than it shows error.

In model:

```php
public static $rules = [
    'name' => 'this field is required'
];
```

In repository:

```php
public function rules()
{
    return State::$rules;
}
```

Comment: Please post your validation rules.

Comment: in model-> public static $rules = [
        'name' => 'this field is required'
    ]; in repository->public function rules()
    {
        return State::$rules;
    }

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code, because adding code in the comments is hard to read since it's unformatted properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing a message as the field rule instead of an actual rule. So your rule should be the following:

```php
public static $rules = [
    'name' => 'required'
];
```

As shown in the [Laravel Validation Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic) a rule is an array of key value pair, where the key is the name of the field that will be validated and the value is the [validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#available-validation-rules). So in your cause the field is `name` and the validation rule is [`required`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-required).

---

If you want to modify the rule validation messages from the default ones found in [`lang/en/validation.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/lang/en/validation.php), you can read about it the [Custom Error Messages](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-error-messages) section of the documentation.